# Error in STS with gradle and Java 9

Tags: java, gradle, spring-tool-suite, java-9

I using STS 3.9.1 with extension Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0, my build.gradle looks:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 9
targetCompatibility = 9

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

and occurs errors:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet. CORE        Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project was not built since it depends on CORE, which has build path errors CORE        Unknown Java Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.9]' in project 'CORE'    CORE        Build path  Build Path Problem

When I create maven project with java 9 everything work properly, anyone know why it doesn't work with gradle?

Comment: I don't think that Spring Boot older than 2.0.0 M? supports JDK9. Also, make sure you have the latest Gradle version.

Comment: Even when I create clear project with java 9 it's still doesn't work. I using gradle 4.2.1

Comment: Any progress on this? I have the same error with Gradle build ship 2.1 and Java 10 in Sts 3.9.4